# Error on installing stylelint: no such file or directory

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2019, npm-install, stylelint

I am trying to install stylelint as explained [here](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started).

When installing i am getting below error:

[image]

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not errors. Those are warnings. This will happen if you are using `npm@6` and install with `--save-dev` when you don't already have a `package.json` file. The results are normal if you don't intend to have a `package.json` file in your project, but that does mean that your dependencies are not being saved in `package.json` for future installation. `npm@6` will create a `package-lock.json` file however.

In general, if you're just messing around to get familiar with `stylelint`, you can ignore the warnings. If you are scaffolding a project, you probably want to create a `package.json` first. To do that quickly, run `npm init`.

If you update to `npm@7`, the warnings do not show up and `npm` creates the `package.json` file for you instead. However it will only contain the `devDependencies` entry when it is created. That may be OK depending on your use case. If in doubt, run `npm init` first.

Comment: ok, I understand, I installed npm (nodejs+npm) from here: nodejs.org/en I installed version 14.15.5 which includes npm 6.14.11. There is a new version 15.8.0 which includes npm 7.5.1. I will take it into account. Also, all my projects have a packages.config file but not package.json, so now I understand why this warning is shown. You are right, in my case, npm is version 6.14.10